# How to Remove the Previous <p> after Display Another <p>?

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript/Css3 Expert,

I have my coding which display texts in sequence, however i need to remove the previous `<p>` text when display another `<p>`.

**In simple words**...I want to replace old displayed texts with upcoming new text and display the final text as it is.

here is the coding:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
p {
  color: lime;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end) forwards;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
p:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
p:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
p:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
p:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
p:nth-child(7) span:first-child {
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
}
span {
  animation: blink 1.8s infinite 8s;
}
p a {
  color: lime;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@keyframes type {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    width: 30em;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
::selection {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<p>Text first.</p>
<p>Text 2nd...</p>
<p>Text 3rd...</p>
<p>Text 4th...</p>
<p>Text 5th...</p>
<p>Text 6th...</p>
<p><span>Final/Blinking Line</span>  <span>|</span>
</p>
```

**Summary:** when you execute the code..it display `<p>` one after another Its Ok..but the `<p>` should replace with one another not to display 4 lines...only last `<p>` blicnking line should be display in the last.

thanks

Comment: Also add your js that you are using.

Comment: I am not using JS i created it in using html and css3 only...You may use JS or Css to do my work...thanks bundles

Comment: If this will grow, you should be removing them from the DOM as you append or it will get clunky and slow. Show your JS please. You need to at least try to make some yourself.

Comment: If you're not using js then why mention it and tag it?

Comment: IF you could use something like that....JS .remove <p> first when display another <p> it should remove then when displayed 3rd <p> it then remove and leave the last as it is...thanks

Comment: I know...it is not possible through Css3, i need some javascript expert to do the stuff...means they should add a piece of code of JS to replace every new text display with another...thanks

Comment: Can you try and modify your animation so it will also handle the hiding of items?

Comment: @Axnyff no brother, if you could help me..try to post your code...i will be really thankful to you

Comment: Anyone know how to deal with it ?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've attempted to implement this and we can work from there.

Comment: bradlyee, welcome to stack overflow and feel free to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) on the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). FYI, asking readers to write code for free is off topic on Stack Overflow, while asking for help with code you've attempted to get working is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS version based on the posted code for some ideas:

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.container {
    position: relative; /* to host absolute child elements */
}
.temporary {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
}

p {
  color: lime;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  animation: type 1s steps(60, end);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
p:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
p:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
p:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
p:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
p:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 5s;
}
p:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

span {
  animation: blink 1.8s infinite 8s;
}

p:nth-child(7) span:first-child {
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
}
p a {
  color: lime;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@keyframes type {
  0% {
  }
  30% {
    width: 10em;
  }
  31% {
    width: 30em;  /* provide reading time for longer lines */
  }
  100% {
    width: 30em;
  }
}
@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
::selection {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<h3>Demo</h3>
<div class="container">
  <p class="temporary">Text first.</p>
  <p class="temporary">Text 2nd...</p>
  <p class="temporary">Text 3rd...</p>
  <p class="temporary">Text 4th... but this is a fairly long line as well.</p>
  <p class="temporary">Text 5th...</p>
  <p class="temporary">Text 6th...</p>
  <p class="temporary"><span>Final/Blinking Line</span>  <span>|</span></p>
</div>
```

Changes:

1. Paragraphs use absolute positioning and are placed within a relatively positioned container so they occupy the same screen area. This was to prevent invisible paragraphs affecting the vertical displacement of visible ones.
2. The animation does not affect paragraph opacity. Animated paragraphs  are specified to have zero width before and after animation. In combination with `overflow: hidden`, this hides paragraphs that are not being animated by default, without using `opacity` or `display` properties.
3. The blinking paragraph is the only one given an `animation-fill-style` of `forwards` to prevent it collapsing back to zero width when animation finishes.

To avoid multiple paragraphs being on display concurrently, the `animation-delay` times for paragraphs need to be not less than the `animation-duration` time of a single paragraph. The amended CSS rules reduce the duration to 1 second to match paragraph delay steps. But then, in order to have longer lines on display for at least 7  tenths of a second,  only the  first 30% of the width expansion is animated before jumping to full width. Some compromise is more or less needed to keep the animation simple, but timings and widths could always be varied according to requirements.

**Blink**

Simulation of CRT text terminal blinking can include a fade out effect to simulate the [persistence time](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12852) of the screen phosphor. Perhaps the simplest way is to provide multiple keyframes for an animation that ramp `opacity` up and down in accordance with graphic design.

As an example this graphic has a blink rate of 1hz, nominal duty cycle of 50% and a rapid phosphor decay of 200ms followed by a slower decay over another 300ms:

```css
.screen {
   font-family: "lucida console", "courier new", monospace;
   color: #0b0;
   background-color: black;
   padding: 1em;
   border-radius: 1em;
   border: thick solid beige;
}

.fadeBlinkText {
   animation-name: fade-blink;
   animation-duration: 1s;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-delay: 2s;
}
.fadeBlinkCursor {
   animation-name: fade-blink;
   animation-duration: 1.5s;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-delay: 2s;
}

@keyframes fade-blink {
   0%    { opacity: 1;}
   20%   { opacity: 0.1;}
   49.9% { opacity: 0.05;}
   50%   { opacity: 1;}
   100%  { opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class=screen>
 <p>Start text blinking in 2 seconds, cursor in 2.5 seconds:

 <p><span class="fadeBlinkText">BLINK BLINK</span><span class="fadeBlinkCursor">|</span>
</div>
```

Comment: you really helped me alot...your code is working fine what i want...the only thing that i want from you is that...>> how to do apply fadout on every paragraph text blink. ? every new blink should disappear with fadout property thats i want...thanks bundle